# Passing Metal texture2d_array to SceneKit shader modifier

Tags: macos, scenekit, metal

I want to create shader modifier for `SCNMaterial` (with `SCNShaderModifierEntryPointSurface`) and pass Metal `texture2d_array` as custom input. To achieve that I try to use key-value coding setting parameter of type `SCNMaterialProperty`. From SceneKit manual on `SCNMaterialProperty` property `contents`:

You can set a value for this property using any of the following types:

- ...
- A texture (SKTexture, MDLTexture, **MTLTexture**, or GLKTextureInfo)
- ...

So, I construct `MTLTexture`:

- Create `MTLTextureDescriptor` with type `MTLTextureType2DArray`
- Create `MTLTexture` with `MTLDevice`'s newTextureWithDescriptor:
- Fill texture with data using `[texture replaceRegion:mipmapLevel:withBytes:bytesPerRow:];`

Then I create `SCNMaterialProperty`, assign my created `MTLTexture` to its `contents` and pass it to material:

```
[material setValue:aTexture forKey:@"tex"];
```

Then I attach this shader modifier:

```
#pragma arguments
texture2d_array tex;

#pragma body
// do sampling from 1st slice
constexpr sampler smp(coord::normalized, address::repeat, filter::nearest);
_surface.diffuse = tex.sample(smp, _surface.diffuseTexcoord, 0);
```

And I get:

[image: exception]

Backtrace:

[image]

I also tried to pass texture directly with `[material setValue:aTexture forKey:@"tex"];` But then I'm getting error:

```
/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Metal/Metal-56.6/ToolsLayers/Debug/MTLDebugRenderCommandEncoder.mm:1600: 
failed assertion `textureType mismatch at texture binding at index 8 for tex[0].'
```

Also, I tried passing `MTLTexture2D` in `SCNMaterialProperty` contents and It fails with exception in C3DImageGetImage type. Passing `MTLTexture2D` directly via `[material setValue:forKey]` results in everything white - wrong texture being sampled.

When analysing 'Capture GPU Frame' output, I see that wrong texture bound during draw call.

Maybe someone managed to pass texture2d_array to shader modifier? Is it possible at all? I could use metal command buffer to bind manually, but how to get access to it on per-material basis?

Thank you all.

Comment: Have you been able to access a simple `texture2d` (instead of a `texture2d_array`) within a shader modifier using this approach? I'm curious as I couldn't seem to get it to work, instead I'm assigning my `MTLTexture`'s to SceneKits various materials (diffuse, specular, normal, etc) as a hack'ish workaround.

Comment: @lock It seems Apple always interpreting material property contents as image when passing as custom input for shader modifier (but I confirm that passing MTLTexture2D to diffuse, specular etc works). When assigning MTLTexture directly without wrapping in SCNMaterialProperty I get no error but all white color - 'Capture GPU Frame' output shows that wrong (white? 4x4) texture bound during draw call. Looks like bug or lack of functionality in SCNMaterialProperty. I could bind texture myself, but I can't figure out how to access SCNRenderContext when drawing nodes that uses certain materials.

Comment: Thanks @EfDot. Your findings seem to line up with what I've seen, especially the white 4x4 texture. I did some looking into the SCNRenderContext to see how I could possibly pass in another MTLTexture (through the render command encoder), without success unfortunately. An SCNProgram will work, but then you have to rewrite your entire shader.

Comment: @lock you welcome. I see no problems in writing whole custom shader using SCNProgram (since any error in shader modifier dumps it to stderr), but when I tried to do that, I loose frustum culling (which I believe is bug in SceneKit).

Answer (score 0):

```
        #include <metal_stdlib>
        #include <metal_texture>
        using namespace metal;
        #pragma arguments
        texture2d<float> mask;

        #pragma body
        constexpr sampler quadSampler(address::clamp_to_edge, filter::linear);

        _surface.diffuse = mask.sample(quadSampler, _surface.diffuseTexcoord);
```

then on swift side

```
let mask = SCNMaterialProperty(contents: MDLTexture(named: "gameFrame.png")!)
doorFrame.geometry?.firstMaterial?.setValue(mask, forKey: "mask")
```

Comment: I believe simple `texture2d` would work, but the question was about `MTLTexture` of type `MTLTextureType2DArray (texture2d_array)`