# Which are the right Matrix Values to use in a metal shader passed by a SCNProgram to get a correct chrome like reflection

Tags: reflection, shader, scenekit, metal, scnprogram

I am working on an App, that should render a chrome-style reflective sphere-like object inside a skybox (using a six faced cube map).

I am doing this in Swift using Scenekit with different approaches.

Everything is fine and perfectly reflected (see Figure 1 below) as long as I let Scenekit doing all the work - in other words, using a standard SCNMaterial with metalness 1.0, roughness 0.0 and color UIColor.white (using .physicallyBased as lighting model) attached to the firstMaterial of the node's geometry (including a directional light).

[image: Figure 1 - correct reflection]

**But the goal is to use a [SCNProgram](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnprogram) instead**, (attached to the node's material) with its own Vertex and Fragment Shader - corresponding to Apples documentation about it. I have a working scenario, but the **reflections are wrong** on the object (as you can see below on Figure 2)

[image: Figure 2 - wrong refelction]

The main question is: **Which are the correct Matrix values** from the **scn_node** or the **scn_frame** (in the shaders.metal file) to use, to get the same reflection on the object as Scenekit does in Figure 1. But using the SCNProgram with the shaders only (and without the light). Unfortunately Apple gives not a lot of information about the different matrices that are filed to the shader by the SCNProgram and which one to use what for - or kind of examples.

Here is my current Vertex Shader in which I assume using some wrong Matrices (I left some out-commented code, to show what was tested already, not out-commented code corresponds 1:1 to Figure 2):

```
vertex SimpleVertexChromeOrig myVertexChromeOrig(MyVertexInput in [[ stage_in ]],
                              constant SCNSceneBuffer& scn_frame [[buffer(0)]],
                              constant MyNodeBuffer& scn_node [[buffer(1)]])
{

SimpleVertexChromeOrig OUT;

OUT.position = scn_node.modelViewProjectionTransform * float4(in.position, 1.0);
// OUT.position = scn_frame.viewProjectionTransform * float4(in.position, 1.0);

float4 eyeSpacePosition  = scn_frame.viewTransform * float4(in.position, 1.0);
float3 eyeSpaceEyeVector = normalize(-eyeSpacePosition).xyz;


// float3 eyeSpaceNormal  = normalize(scn_frame.inverseViewTransform * float4(in.normal, 1.0)).xyz;
float3 eyeSpaceNormal  = normalize(scn_node.normalTransform * float4(in.normal, 1.0)).xyz;

// Reflection and Refraction Vectors
float3 eyeSpaceReflection = reflect(-eyeSpaceEyeVector, eyeSpaceNormal);
OUT.worldSpaceReflection  = (scn_node.inverseModelViewTransform * float4(eyeSpaceReflection, 1.0)).xyz;
// OUT.worldSpaceReflection  = (scn_node.modelViewTransform * float4(eyeSpaceReflection, 1.0)).xyz;
// OUT.worldSpaceReflection  = (scn_node.modelTransform * float4(eyeSpaceReflection, 1.0)).xyz;

return OUT;
}
```

Here is the current Fragment Shader (very default with cube-map sampler):

```
fragment float4 myFragmentChromeOrig(SimpleVertexChromeOrig in [[stage_in]],
                texturecube<float, access::sample> cubeTexture [[texture(0)]],
                sampler cubeSampler [[sampler(0)]])
{

float3 reflection = cubeTexture.sample(cubeSampler, in.worldSpaceReflection).rgb;

float4 color;
color.rgb = reflection;
color.a   = 1.0;

return color;
}
```

This are the Matrices I get from the NodeBuffer (kind of automatically provided by the SCNProgram) - they must be just defined in a struct in the shader file to be accessible like so:

```
struct MyNodeBuffer {
    float4x4 modelTransform;
    float4x4 inverseModelTransform;
    float4x4 modelViewTransform;
    float4x4 inverseModelViewTransform;
    float4x4 normalTransform;
    float4x4 modelViewProjectionTransform;
    float4x4 inverseModelViewProjectionTransform;
};
```

This is the Vertex Input struct:

```
typedef struct {
    float3 position [[ attribute(SCNVertexSemanticPosition) ]];
    float3 normal [[ attribute(SCNVertexSemanticNormal) ]]; // Phil
} MyVertexInput;
```

This is the Stuct filled by the Vertex Shader:

```
struct SimpleVertexChromeOrig
{
    float4 position [[position]];
    float3 worldSpaceReflection;
};
```

(The Skybox is always provided trough a SCNMaterialContent Property containing six images and is attached to sceneView.scene.background.contents)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possible formulations that will work for this, but I've included one that appeared to work for me below. The comments explain each step.

```
vertex SimpleVertexChromeOrig myVertexChromeOrig(MyVertexInput in [[stage_in]],
                                                 constant SCNSceneBuffer& scn_frame [[buffer(0)]],
                                                 constant MyNodeBuffer& scn_node [[buffer(1)]])
{
    float4 modelSpacePosition(in.position, 1.0f);
    float4 modelSpaceNormal(in.normal, 0.0f);

    // We'll be computing the reflection in eye space, so first we find the eye-space
    // position. This is also used to compute the clip-space position below.
    float4 eyeSpacePosition = scn_node.modelViewTransform * modelSpacePosition;

    // We compute the eye-space normal in the usual way.
    float3 eyeSpaceNormal = (scn_node.normalTransform * modelSpaceNormal).xyz;

    // The view vector in eye space is just the vector from the eye-space position.
    float3 eyeSpaceViewVector = normalize(-eyeSpacePosition.xyz);

    // To find the reflection vector, we reflect the (inbound) view vector about the normal.
    float4 eyeSpaceReflection = float4(reflect(-eyeSpaceViewVector, eyeSpaceNormal), 0.0f);

    // To sample the cubemap, we want a world-space reflection vector, so multiply
    // by the inverse view transform to go back from eye space to world space.
    float3 worldSpaceReflection = (scn_frame.inverseViewTransform * eyeSpaceReflection).xyz;

    SimpleVertexChromeOrig out;
    out.position = scn_frame.projectionTransform * eyeSpacePosition;
    out.worldSpaceReflection = worldSpaceReflection;
    return out;
}

fragment float4 myFragmentChromeOrig(SimpleVertexChromeOrig in [[stage_in]],
                                     texturecube<float, access::sample> cubeTexture [[texture(0)]],
                                     sampler cubeSampler [[sampler(0)]])
{
    // Since the reflection vector's length will vary under interpolation, we normalize it
    // and flip it from the assumed right-hand space of the world to the left-hand space
    // of the interior of the cubemap.
    float3 worldSpaceReflection = normalize(in.worldSpaceReflection) * float3(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);

    float3 reflection = cubeTexture.sample(cubeSampler, worldSpaceReflection).rgb;
    float4 color;
    color.rgb = reflection;
    color.a   = 1.0;
    return color;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The result is absolutely perfect and fantastic.

Comment: guys, how did you pass the cubeSampler to the fragment function from the cpu side?

Comment: - Reason I ask, because altho Ive managed to pass sampleState using a command encoder to a fragment func Ive not yet managed to pass one over into an SCNProgram identified frag function, im actually in the middle of reading a primer on vertex data in metal by example trying to get my head around this gpu stuff - it really is a big step away from the swift and swiftui im comfortable with .....

Comment: That's a separate question, but it happens to already be answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45678137/155187

Comment: sorry warren, I might be completely misunderstanding things here and maybe not properly distinguishing between the sampler and the texture2d - say I have a frag function that has three args, 1: a vertex out from a vertex func 2: a texture2d<float, access::sample> tex2dInput [[texture(0)]] and lastly a sampler: eg: sampler passedSampler [[sampler(0)]], I know I can instantiate a sampler within the body of the function rg: constexpr sampler texSampler(coord::normalized, address::repeat, filter::linear); then derive a float4 or half4 from the sampler and the text co-ord out from the...

Comment: ...vertex func, but what im trying to figure out is how to pass a sampler that I've made from a sampleDescriptor over to a frag func that I've cited in a SCNProgram in the same way as I would if I were using a MTLRenderCommandEncoder and using its .setFragmentSamplerState(custom sampler here, index: (whatever))   method.... getting a metal texture over is fine using a SCNMaterialProperty just stuck on the sampler - I realise this is a separate question but I've another post with my question and came across this during some reading

Comment: Not possible as far as I know. SceneKit creates and configures a sampler state on your behalf based on the properties of the material property.